# Pointer to file stream for unmanaged DLL

Tags: c#, .net, dll, unmanaged, unmanaged-memory

I have a 3rd party unmanaged DLL that wants me to supply them with a pointer (takes a IntPtr) to a huge continuous block of memory (around 500 MB). While it doesn't exceed the amount of memory we can work with, it is common to not be able to get a continuous block of memory that large without getting errors. This block of memory is just a image buffer and while it is unlikely to consume all of it if I try to supply it a smaller block and it consumes it it crashes. Also note that the large amount of memory is the maximum size the device supports, but the amount the device needs at any given time is based on what the user is doing with the device.

The 3rd party is unwilling to make any changes to their DLL. I asked if they would be will to just take a file path and have the DLL dump the data to a raw file on the hard drive.

Anyway, I don't know how to word what I am looking for, and I doubt it is even possible, but I am looking for some way of passing in a IntPtr that instead of pointing to a continuous block of memory points to a file stream or something that goes straight to a file on the hard drive. Is something like that possible? If so, what kind of .Net namespace do I need to look in.

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [**Where to Start**](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6366/where-to-start/6367#6367), then address your post.

Comment: Working with blocks of memory that large, you probably should be using 64-bit processes on 64-bit Windows. From your description, it seems that you have a requirement that one way or another you get a pointer in memory to a contiguous block of address space that is 500MB large, and even if you map that to a file (see memory-mapped files), you're still going to need the _address space_ in your process. Finally note that even on 32-bit Windows, if a 500MB byte[] array object is the very first thing you allocate in your problem, that _should_ work fine.

Comment: You could try using a MemoryMappedFile (You can get an address using unsafe code via the MemoryMappedViewAccessor.SafeMemoryMappedViewHandle)

Comment: "it is common to not be able to get a continuous block of memory that large without getting errors"
No virtual memory?

Comment: I never did get that approach to work, but discovered the 3rd party had an alternate mode where you could pass in 65kb buffers 1 after the other instead of a full 500 mb buffer, so I solved my problem by passing in 65kb buffers, writing it to a RAW file, and then clearing and reusing the buffer. Didn't notice any logic or performance problems either.